# Append date/timestamp to existing files

Tags: shell, unix, find, rename, aix

There are few files in a directory. I would like to find all the files based on wildcard criteria and then rename it by appending a date or timestamp field to it using single line command

Example :
foo1.txt
foo1.log
foo2.txt
foo2.log

I want to find all .log files and rename them by appending date field to it

Expected output :
foo1.txt
foo1_20210609.log
foo2.txt
foo2_20210609.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a "for" loop over the wildcard list of matches and then use parameter expansion and command substitution to splice out the rest:

```sh
for file in *.log
do
  echo mv -- "$file" "${file%.log}_$(date +%Y%m%d).log"
done
```

The pieces in the middle break down as:

- `mv --` -- invoke "mv" and explicitly tell it that there are no more options; this insulates us from filenames that might start with `-i`, for example
- `"${file%.log}` -- expands the "$file" variable and removes the ".log" from the end
- `_` -- just adds the underscore where we want it
- `$(date +%Y%m%d)` -- calls out to the `date` command and inserts the resulting output
- `.log` -- just adds the ".log" part back at the end

Remove the "echo" if you like the resulting commands.
If you want a static timestamp, then just use that text in place of the whole `$(date ...)` command substitution.

On your sample input, but with today's date, the output is:

```sh
mv -- foo1.log foo1_20210610.log
mv -- foo2.log foo2_20210610.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | perl -lne '$date=`date '+%Y%m%d'`; chomp($date); `mv $_ $_$date`;'
```

1. ls the file
2. pipe it into a perl script
3. e option executes in line
4. n option splits the input into lines
5. l option adds new line to each

back ticks execute unix commands

Comment: Beware of _rare_ (but _perfectly legal_) filenames such as "foo bar.log" or $'foo\nbar.log' which will be mis-parsed by `ls | ...`.  I think the OP also wants to limit the changes to ".log" files, while the bare `ls` here would also grab their "foo1.txt" file.